# Pandas read_csv with chunksize memory leak

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am enriching a csv with 750 million rows by using pandas **read_csv** with a chunksize of 500000 and writing out to another csv file. Running this I get a **'segmentation fault'** after processing around 100-150 million rows.

I kept track of number of chunks processed and altered the code so it would skip the chunks it had read. Monitoring the process memory consumption I see that it increases a lot even though I'm skipping the chunks. That's the part that I don't get. Going through the questions there seems to have been an issue with pandas garbage collection, but that seems to relate to previous versions. I'm using Python **2.7** and pandas **0.21.0**

I'm doing this on a r3.xlarge EC2 instance with 30 GB RAM, which should be enough, even taking into account pandas up to 6x memory overhead.

Code summary:

```
i = 0
for chunk in pd.read_csv(filename,chunksize=500000,names=colnames):
    if  i <= 349500000: # Previously processed chunks
        i = i+chunksize
        print 'Skipping chunk ', i
        continue
    enriched_chunk = enrich_df(chunk, users_df)
    enriched_chunk.to_csv('enriched.csv', mode='a', header=False, index=False)


def enrich_df(c, users_df):
    d = pd.merge(c, users_df, how='left', left_on='user_id', right_on='userId')
    return d
```

The table users_df is a relatively small table that is kept in memory.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a simplified test script and cannot reproduce your error. I am using Python 3.6.1 and Pandas 0.20.3.

The test script uses a constant 306 MB of RAM (at least for the first 100 million rows, it's still running).

[image: RAM usage of test script]

You could try this script and see if it still produces the memory leak with you? It can serve as a starting point for your debugging.

```
import os
import time

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

SOURCE = 'test.csv'
CHUNCKSIZE = int(5e5)

def main():

    if not os.path.exists(SOURCE):
        df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(1000000, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
        df.to_csv(SOURCE)
        del df
    print("df %s ready" %(SOURCE))

    i=0; lines=[]; timings = []
    while(i < int(7e8)): 
        t = time.time()
        print(i, end = ' ')
        i += CHUNCKSIZE
        chunk = pd.read_csv(SOURCE, chunksize=CHUNCKSIZE)
        chunk = pd.concat(chunk, ignore_index=True)
        chunk.to_csv('enriched.csv', mode='a', header=False, index=False)
        print(" in %.3f seconds" %(time.time() -t))
        lines.append(i)
        timings.append(time.time()-t)


    plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
    plt.plot(lines, timings, 'o-')
    plt.xlabel("Nr of lines"); plt.ylabel("Time for last chunck")
    plt.show()




if __name__ == "__main__":
    st = time.time()
    main()
    print("--- total runtime %.3f seconds ---" %(time.time() - st))
```